# eclipse for sun one server for debugging and running application

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jdk1.4, sunone

Is there a way to add sun one application server 7 to eclipse IDE. Its for maintaining an enterprise application project. The jdk is also 1.4 used for the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Sun One Application server is now the [Oracle GlassFish Server](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/application-server/oracle-glassfish-server/index.html).  Eclipse has support for the GlassFish server runtime.  If it is not already installed, you can get it here: https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/

Sun also has a product that is the Sun One Java System Web Server.  MyEclipse 8.5 M2 looks like it supports that product based on this [forum post](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-printview-t-24104-start-15.html).  [MyEclipseIDE application server connectors](http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?module=htmlpages&func=display&pid=55)

We use Sun One Java System Web Server 7 and develop using the Apache Tomcat server runtime and have not had any issues when deploying our war files to the Sun Web Server 7.

Comment: can EJBs be setup and debugged using Sun One Java System Web Server & and tomcat server runtime as the application am trying to maintain and enhance has it. Also it really needs jdk1.4 . If its compiled with anything above. there will be problems on the production. Strangely nothing happens on the stage. But product no way supports it.

Comment: GlassFish seems to require jdk1.5+ too.

Comment: @zapping:  The Sun Web Server and Tomcat Server are both Servlet Containers so they do not support EJB's.  You would need an application server for that, but GlassFish is JDK1.5+.  For EJB's and JDK 1.4 compatibility, JBoss Application Server is your best bet.