# how to configure Sun One in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, sunone

I need a step by step method because I have never used a server like this in Eclipse.

Do you have some installation tips and tutorial links for this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this old [GlassFish FAQ](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=GlassFishFAQ#section-GlassFishFAQ-WhatIsTheDifferenceBetweenSunOneSJSASAndGlassFish):

> **What is the difference between SunOne, SJSAS, and GlassFish?**
>
> SunOne is an old branding which was replaced by Sun Java System some time ago.
> Sun Java System Application Server is the supported version of GlassFish.
> Specifically, SJSAS 9.0 PE and GlassFish v1 are the same bits (except for the installer). Similarly SJS AS 9.1 and GlassFish v2 will be the same.

(See also the SO question "[eclipse for sun one server for debugging and running application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691150/eclipse-for-sun-one-server-for-debugging-and-running-application)")

So you could rather declare a GlassFish server in your Eclipse.
Actually, at https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/, you have a link to download a Eclipse Galileo preconfigured with the GlassFish v3 Java EE 6 runtime.

From there, you can fond [some tutorials](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/GlassFishV2_Web_Tutorial) (like [this one](http://server.dzone.com/blogs/arungupta/2008/06/27/glassfish-eclipse-ganymede)) to configure your GlassFish server in Eclipse.